# CurlPP won't do requests multiple times

Tags: c++, while-loop, curlpp

I am using CurlPP to get the public IP address of a network by using the API of https://ipify.org
My function works fine, however, it only does when called up to 4-6 times.
I am calling the function in a while loop to check for changes of the IP address. (It sometimes works for 4 times, sometimes for 5 or 6 times).
After that, nothing happens, no output, nothing, just the cursor blinking in the terminal, no error or anything!

```
std::string getIPAddress()
{

    try
    {
        curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;
        {
            std::ostringstream ip_address_stream;
            ip_address_stream << curlpp::options::Url("http://api.ipify.org");
            ip_address = ip_address_stream.str();
            return ip_address;
        }
    }
    catch(curlpp::RuntimeError &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(curlpp::LogicError &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that api you're using isn't rate limited ? Try adding a (longer) sleep between requests.

Comment: Yes, the API doesn't limit requests. Sleep also doesn't solve it. I have however an idea what it's about: While running the curlpp requests I am connecting to a VPN. So I assume that during the time there's no usable network interface, curlpp throws an error that I don't catch, although I think It should be catched as a runtime error?

Comment: if you're unsure whether you catch all exceptions, you can use `catch (...)`. Alternatively, have a look at the network http traffic (using wireshark eg.) to see if you spot an oddity there.